# Is it possible to make a 16-column row inside a 12-column layout using Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, less

I have a standard 12-column layout for my overall site. Within one of the columns, I need the ability to separate into 16 additional columns.

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="tools"></div>
   <div class="content">
      <div class="row">
         <div class="col1"></div>
         <div class="col2"></div>
         <div class="col3"></div>
         <div class="col4"></div>
         <div class="col5"></div>
         <div class="col6"></div>
         <div class="col7"></div>
         <div class="col8"></div>
         <div class="col9"></div>
         <div class="col10"></div>
         <div class="col11"></div>
         <div class="col12"></div>
         <div class="col13"></div>
         <div class="col14"></div>
         <div class="col15"></div>
         <div class="col16"></div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

My LESS looks like this:

```
.row { 
   .make-row();
   .tools { .make-md-column(3) }
   .content { 
      .make-md-column(3);
      div {
         @grid-columns:              16;
         @grid-gutter-width:         10px;
         @grid-float-breakpoint:     768px;
         .make-md-columns(1);
      }
    }
```

I was hoping I could use the Bootstrap 3 mixins and create some local variables to quickly create a single instance of a 16-column grid, but my approach doesn't work; I end up with a standard 12-column grid for those 16 inner columns.

Is this something that's not possible or am I misunderstanding how this should be done?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not duplicate, but you can find your answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19724075/1596547. In summary Bootstrap doesn't support sub grid, so at the moment it is not possible compile your sub / second with the same code and settings.

Possible solution will be to compile your sub grid separate and integrate the CSS in your project.

Use something like:

```
// Core variables and mixins
@import "variables.less";
@import "mixins.less";

@grid-columns: 16;
@media (min-width: @screen-md-min) {
  .make-grid-columns-float(md16);
  .make-grid(@grid-columns, md16, width);
  .make-grid(@grid-columns, md16, pull);
  .make-grid(@grid-columns, md16, push);
  .make-grid(@grid-columns, md16, offset);
}
```